# JQuery Name attribute of children

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

Can anyone help me out here getting the name value of the input - submit?

```
<form action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="DeleteProductFromWinkelwagenForm">
  <td class="tdWinkelwagen">
     <input type="hidden" name="<?php echo $product->getProductId() ?>" value="<?php echo $product->getProductId() ?>"/>
     <input type="submit" name="<?php echo $product->getProductId() ?>" value="" title="deleteIcon" class="button"/>
   </td>  
</form>
```

Another problem is that this code is generated unknown amount of times, everytime with another name (productId which comes from PHP). 
Generated multiple times on the same page.
I also made a script that displays an animation.

How can I know here which submit is clicked and display personalized animation for each submit?

Thanks!

Comment: Is the code generated multiple times on the same page, or is it just once?

Comment: Multiple times on the same page

Answer (score 4):

In order to perform specific animation for specific submit button:

```
$(document).on('click', 'input[type="submit"]', function() {
   var that = $(this);
   var name = that.attr('name');
   if (name == 'a_name') {
      // perform animation for 'a_name'
   } else if (name == 'b_name') {
      // ...
   }
})
```

If there is actually a name attribute, it will be caught. Check the code bellow (name = test):

```js
$(document).on('click', 'input[type="submit"]', function(e) {
   var that = $(this);
   var name = that.attr('name');
  e.preventDefault();
  alert(name);
   if (name == 'test') {
      // perform animation for 'a_name'
   } else if (name == 'b_name') {
      // ...
   }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="DeleteProductFromWinkelwagenForm">
  <td class="tdWinkelwagen">
     <input type="hidden" name="test" value="<?php echo $product->getProductId() ?>"/>
     <input type="submit" name="test" value="submit" title="deleteIcon" class="button" />
   </td>  
</form>
```

Comment: "Undefined" in Console

Comment: sounds like you do not have an "name" on the input than.

Comment: The code is exactly as copied in my post. And i Think you also just copied it multiple times

Comment: And when I inspect elements in HTML source in browser, the php echo has been done, the name is set

Comment: The HTML should be the same in order to demonstrate the example. The submit button has a name attribute equal to 'test'. Check if PHP writes the name attribute or if it is null.

Comment: Problem solved by form inside <td> and not <td> inside <form>. Now I do get output

Answer (score 2):

You can use this:

```
var name = $('.DeleteProductFromWinkelwagenForm').find('[type="submit"]').attr('name');
console.log(name);
```

---

or within a context like:

```
var name = $(this).closest('.DeleteProductFromWinkelwagenForm').find('[type="submit"]').attr('name');
console.log(name);
```

---

I suggest you to better to use with `submit` event. check the demo below:

```js
$('form').submit(function(){
    var name = $(this).find('[type="submit"]').attr('name');
    alert(name);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="DeleteProductFromWinkelwagenForm">
  <td class="tdWinkelwagen">
    <input type="hidden" name="<?php echo $product->getProductId() ?>" value="<?php echo $product->getProductId() ?>" />
    <input type="submit" name="1" value="submit" title="deleteIcon" class="button" />
  </td>
</form>
<form action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="DeleteProductFromWinkelwagenForm">
  <td class="tdWinkelwagen">
    <input type="hidden" name="<?php echo $product->getProductId() ?>" value="<?php echo $product->getProductId() ?>" />
    <input type="submit" name="2" value="submit" title="deleteIcon" class="button" />
  </td>
</form>
<form action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="DeleteProductFromWinkelwagenForm">
  <td class="tdWinkelwagen">
    <input type="hidden" name="<?php echo $product->getProductId() ?>" value="<?php echo $product->getProductId() ?>" />
    <input type="submit" name="3" value="submit" title="deleteIcon" class="button" />
  </td>
</form>
<form action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="DeleteProductFromWinkelwagenForm">
  <td class="tdWinkelwagen">
    <input type="hidden" name="<?php echo $product->getProductId() ?>" value="<?php echo $product->getProductId() ?>" />
    <input type="submit" name="4" value="submit" title="deleteIcon" class="button" />
  </td>
</form>
```

Comment: Here i get "undefined" in the console

Comment: @Kemagezien added a demo you can take a look at it.

Comment: I See it works, when i try this on another form, and use 'form' and not classname in JQuery. It does work. However on my example it still outputs "undefined"

Comment: do all of you forms have the same class?

Comment: Yes. class="DeleteProductFromWinkelwagenForm"

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.DeleteProductFromWinkelwagenForm').submit(function() {
    var hiddenValue = $(this).find("[type='hidden']").attr('value');
    var hiddenname  = $(this).find("[type='hidden']").attr('name');
    console.log(hiddenValue);
    console.log(hiddenname  );
});
```

EDIT: here as JSFiddle with alerts and returns false so the form doesnt navigate
https://jsfiddle.net/5onmwLm6/1/

Comment: Both return "Undefined" to the console

Comment: can you go to the developers console and check that both, name and value are set correctly?

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function(){
    $('form').on('click', 'input', function() {
        var $input = $(this);
        var attrName = $input.attr('name');
        if (typeof(attrName) !== 'undefined' && attrName !== '') {
            alert('you clicked on input with name ' + attrName);
        }
        else {
            alert('you clicked on input with udefined name');
        }
    });
});
```